# What is the proper CLI command to transfer Solana delegated tokens?

Tags: solana-cli

Account B delegated authority to Account A for n tokens. Now Account A wants to transfer tokens to Account C using delegated amount. CLI command is needed.

I tried running the below command. the default account is Account A.

```
spl-token transfer <mint address> <amount> <AccountC Address> --from <AccountB TokenAddress>
```

Answer (score 2):

You're very close! For a delegate, you want to pass them as the `--owner` of the account, so try:

```
spl-token transfer <mint address> <amount> <AccountC Address> --from <AccountB TokenAddress> --owner <AccountA Address>
```

Using https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/7f8e5bb99015842a22e9cfbfca35d9072405fa03/token/cli/src/main.rs#L5821 as a reference test that checks this behavior